# What is the correct generalization of degree of a divisor to the number field case?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

When describing smooth algebraic curves over a field $k$, there are (at least) two useful notions of "class group". The first generalizes easily to general schemes: the Picard group can be defined as the group of Cartier divisors modulo linear equivalence, and for the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field, the Picard group is the ideal class group of fractional ideals modulo principal ideals.

However, there is a difference: the ideal class group of a number field is always finite, while the class group of a smooth projective curve $X$ is infinite, and classified by *degree*. This is defined to be (at least when $k = \overline{k}$ is algebraically closed) the sum of the multiplicities of a divisor $D$ at each closed point $x \in k$. It's well-defined on ideal classes due to the crucial property that $\deg (f) = 0$ for $(f)$ a principal divisor. The subgroup generated by elements of degree $0$ is the invariant $\text{Pic}^0(X)$, which is actually an abelian variety of dimension equal to the genus of the curve.

Why are these two types of behavior so different? Is there a way to define a notion of degree and $\text{Pic}^0$ for a number field $K$? One fact that seems promising is the product formula $\prod_\nu |x|_\nu = 1$ where $\nu$ runs through *all* places of $K$, both finite and infinite. If the extra infinite places are supposed to be analogous to the points at infinity of a projective curve, can we extend this analogy to define the degree of a fractional ideal? While the valuation at the finite places clearly can be extended, it's unclear what to do about the infinite places here.

Comment: Anyway, I think "Arakelov geometry" might be a good keyword here.

Comment: In the finite field case, doesn't the fact that principal divisors have degree $0$ still hold? So $\text{Pic}(X)$ should still have an infinite component.

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I would imagine the difference is that $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_K$ is affine.

Comment: @Nefertiti That seems to be exactly the problem. In the case, say, of an elliptic curve, we can glimpse $\operatorname{Pic}^0(E)$ in an affine open set where we look at the group of its points, which "appear" to be in degree $1$, not $0$; the isomorphism with $\operatorname{Pic}^0(E)$ comes from mapping $P$ to $P - O$, with $O$ the point at infinity. I know that in some sense, the archimedean places of a number field are supposed to be "points at infinity" - is there any nice construction like this that works here?

Comment: @Dorebell While this doesn't answer your question, the Adeles do sort of play this role, but algebraically it's got zero divisors so it sucks in that regard. They're used mostly for doing analysis from my understanding.

Algebraically, recently I've been thinking about the ring $\mathcal{O}_K((q))$. This is a Dedekind domain with uncountably many prime ideals. You can tensor over $\mathcal{O}_K$ with $K$, and you'd still have uncountably many prime ideals, with residue fields all finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_{\mathfrak{p}}$. I have no idea what the class group would be though.

Comment: Cool! Can you point me to a reference about this ring? (I don't know much of anything about adeles either).

Comment: @Dorebell As Qiaochu mentioned, the correct thing to think about here is Arakelov geometry. In particular, the that one would want to do on a 'compactification' of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ in general is *intersection theory* (defining degree being a basic part of this). This was, in fact, one of the original goals of Arakelov geometry—to attempt to prove something like, say, the Mordell conjecture similar to how one proves the Weil conjectures (for curves): by looking at analogues of $\Delta\cap\Gamma_\mathrm{Frob}$.